# Adding Columns (SQL Queries) to a CSV File in Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, csv

I have been unable to figure out how to write additional columns, not rows, to a CSV file in Ruby.  In this case, they are SQL queries.

Snippet of my code:

```
month = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%m') FROM company_db.dates.starting_date;")

day = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%d') FROM company_db.dates.starting_date;")

year = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%Y') FROM company_db.dates.starting_date;")

CSV.open("Dates.csv, "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Month", "Day", "Year"]
  csv << [(month.each {|row| csv << row}), (day.each {|row| csv << row}), (year.each {|row| csv << row})]
end
```

The output I get:

```
Month, Day, Year
1,
.
.
.
12,
1,
.
.
.
31,
1970,
  .
  .
  .
2015
```

And the output I desire:

```
Month, Day, Year
1, 1, 1970
.  .    .
.   .    .
.    .    .
12, 31, 2015
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you combine your three sql statements into one? `mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%m'), DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%d'), DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%Y') FROM company_db.dates.starting_date;")`

Comment: I know how to do that.  That wasn't the question I asked.

Comment: Can you show the output object of your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Enumerable.zip is the method you are looking for.

Given your three queries:

```
csv << [ 'Month', 'Day', 'Year' ]
csv << month.zip( day, year )
```

Comment: I get the following error:

`iMac:Workspace guy$ ruby File.rb
File.rb:105:in 'block in <main>': undefined method 'zip' for #<Mysql::Result:0x007fd3e11add00> (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/guy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1282:in 'open'
 from File:103:in '<main>'`

I used your exact code as well.

Comment: Not knowing which Gem you were using for your Mysql connectivity, I was hopping that the .each interface exposed by the result was coming from Enumerable, which apparently it isn't with what you are using.

Both `mysql2` & `sequel` ( gems ) support the Enumerable interface that would make the above work.

Comment: The `mysql2` gem records a query as a `hash => value` pair instead of an array so I may need to play around with my code some more to get it working.  It did add everything by column instead of row, so this did help me out a lot.  Thank you.

Comment: You can tell mysql2 to return arrays instead of hashes.

`Mysql2::Client.default_query_options.merge!(:as => :array)` early in your script should make the change for the lifetime of your script.

Comment: That helped a lot as well, but now I have `["10"]` for example instead of just `10` in a given column.  What has been really stumping me for hours  is if I wish to, instead of joining the query for `year`, if I were to stick a multi-column `SELECT` into that `.zip` that all the information is contained in one column and I haven't been able to split it.  I may end up asking a less-simplified and more specific question even though you originally answered my question here.

Answer (score -1):

```
results = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%m') AS month, DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%d') AS date, DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%Y') AS year FROM company_db.dates.starting_date;")

CSV.open("Dates.csv, "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Month", "Day", "Year"]
  results.each do |row|
    csv << [row.month, row.date, row.year]
  end
end
```

Comment: You meant to write:

`CSV.open("Dates.csv, "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Month", "Day", "Year"]
  mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%m'),
  DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%d'),
  DATE_FORMAT(company_db.dates.starting_date,'%Y')
  FROM company_db.dates.starting_date;").each {|row| csv << row}
end`

Without answering my question.

Comment: The, `AS month`, and so on will give an error.  It is also redundant, as the `csv << ["Month", "Day", "Year"]` already establishes column headers.  I am setting separate queries equal to different variables because I eventually need to split rows and manipulate the number of rows based on a date I pull from the database.  I.e. if a starting date is earlier in one row than another, that row would get more rows during a split.  I also couldn't find another question on SO that gives a direct answer to this problem.  I was hoping to get to that answer.