# Creating CSV Using Multiple Ruby Queries Across All Columns

Tags: mysql, arrays, ruby, csv

I am using Ruby to automate reporting from a remote MySQL database.  I am using multiple queries (and not joining them into one) as I eventually wish to split rows based off a given value in one or several columns.  It also gives me the option to work across different databases or even different hosts.

I am using the `mysql2`, `watir` and `csv` Ruby gems.

My code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "mysql2"
require "watir"
require "csv"

puts "Initializing Report"

Mysql2::Client.default_query_options.merge!(:as => :array)

mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "1.2.3.4", :username => "user", :pass => "password", :database => "db")

puts "Successfully accessed db"

month = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m') FROM db.table WHERE db.start.group = 1;")

report = mysql.query("SELECT db.table.name, db.table.company, db.table.type FROM db.table WHERE db.start.group = 1;")

CSV.open("Report.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Month", "Name", "Company", "Type"]
  month.zip(report).each {|row| csv << row}
end

puts "Results can be found in Report.csv"
```

Now that `report` query is much bigger, spanning several dozen columns and several thousand rows made from almost a dozen `INNER JOIN`s and `WHERE` criteria.  It has been simplified for this question.

The output the above code gives me, in a CSV file, is:

```
Month, Name, Company, Type
["1"], ["Adam", "companyrecordlabel", "Ficticious"]
["1"], ["Alana", "beeUrself", "Made-up"]
  .                   .
  .                   .
  .                   .
["12"], ["Zed", "Meds4U", "Fake"]
```

and the output I desire:

```
Month, Name, Company, Type
1, Adam, companyrecordlabel, Ficticious
1, Alana, beeUrself, Made-up
.             .
.             .
.             .
12, Zed, Meds4U, Fake
```

I have been struggling with this for hours and I cannot seem to get the output I want.

I have read CSV files, outputted multiple (and multi-dimensional) arrays to a .txt file and written a single (large) query to a CSV file without the brackets or quotation marks; but I cannot seem to achieve this.

Thank you for any and all help in advance.

Edit: I was using help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588482/adding-columns-sql-queries-to-a-csv-file-in-ruby) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use following code

```
month.zip(report).each {|row| csv << row.flatten}
```

Comment: You did it; and just with one method too.  You absolute madman.  I probably should have been looking [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten) instead of [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-zip).